# MySQL Error 1452 Inserting Data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert data into a database I have designed, and am receiving an error 1452.

SOLVED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the error concerned most likely you don't have rows in one or all parent tables (`Customer`, `Branch`, `AccountTypes`) with PK values that you're trying to refer to in your `INSERT` statement (`1`, `"40-20-23"`, `"Current"` accordingly).

Insert these rows first

```sql
INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName, ...) VALUES(...);
INSERT INTO Branch (BranchSortCode, ...) VALUES('40-20-23', ...);
INSERT INTO AccountTypes (AccountType, ...) VALUES('Current', ...);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/393f8/1)** demo